# Why can't a variable be incremented in an assignment operator?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, variable-assignment, modulus

As a preface, I am using eclipse 3.7.2 on Mint 12x64

Suppose you have the given fields:

```
tail = 10;
capacity = 10;
```

Now suppose you were to execute this statement:

```
tail++ %= capacity;
```

Why is the statement illegal? Is the statement ambiguous? To me it seems that it would evaluate in the an order such as:

- tail = modulus capacity
- tail increments by one

Answer (score 6):

The result of the expression `tail++` is a *value*, not a variable. From the JLS, Section [15.14.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2):

> The result of the postfix increment expression is not a variable, but a value.

You can't assign to a value, only to a variable (or field).

Comment: That makes sense now. The statement was completely based on my thought that the variable was returned not the value of the variable. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 5):

The reason why your sample does not compile is because `tail++` is a **value**, not a **variable**. The `++` operator takes a variable (and increments it), and then returns a **value**, which you then try to assign to. You can only assign to variables, hence the compiler error. If you want to make your sample work, you could try:

```
tail %= capacity;
tail++;
```